# npm is is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: node.js, npm, npx

I have small problem with npm and npx. When I run the following command:

```
npm -v
```

it prints the following:

> ```
> CALL "C:\*******\node.exe" "C::\*******\\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" prefix -g' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
> operable program or batch file.
> 6.14.13
> ```

Node is in the PATH directories environment.

Comment: I'm not 100% however it seems as theres an issue with the installed node.js. Have you tried reinstalling it and/or checking its path?

Comment: The problem is solved. Thanks to everyone for their help.